# How to make sense of fractions concretely

Tags: fractions

I can solve fractions abstractly, for example, $\frac{5}{2}$ divided by $\frac{3}{2}$, you can flip $\frac{3}{2}$ so that $\frac{5}{2}$ multiplied by $\frac{2}{3}$. Specifically, math makes sense abstractly, but concretely it just won't make sense, like in word problems. I understand the concept of complex fractions I know how to solve them, but by applying it on practical use  such as a shape it does not make sense. How to make sense of fractions concretely?? or perhaps there is a book that you can advice me that help solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

So what you would like to know is why $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{a\cdot d}{b\cdot c}$$

to understand this you first need to understand $\frac{1}{x}\cdot x=1$. Knowng this we can see $\frac{c}{d}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{c}{d}}=1\implies \frac{1}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{d}{c}$ (just assume $\frac{c}{d}$ is $x$).

Therefore

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{a}{b}\frac{d}{c}=\frac{ad}{bc}$$

as desired.

Comment: Again as I told I understand the abstract way of dividing a/b by c/d. But if I put it in concrete way like in terms of a shape or practical means it does not make sense. So what I want is to make sense of it concretely. Again I understand the concept of complex fractions

Comment: If you really understand it abstractly then you should understand it concretely also.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $\dfrac{a}b$ denotes the quantity $x$, which when multiplied by $b$ gives $a$. In fact, this is the correct way to interpret $\dfrac{a}b$.

In your case, $\dfrac{5/2}{3/2}$ denotes the quantity $x$, which when multiplied by $\dfrac32$ gives us $\dfrac52$, i.e., $$\dfrac32x = \dfrac52 \implies x = \dfrac53$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example: $5/2$ divided by $3/2$ is the number of bottles of $3/2$ liters that you need to complete $5/2$ liters. What is the same that how many bottles of $3$ liters are needed to contain $5$ liters. That is, $5/3$ bottles.

Comment: Alternatively, if $5/2$L represents $3/2$ containers, then how big is one container? "Partitive" and "Quotative " are good words to Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is a playlist of videos especially targeted to understand fractions concretely, hope you enjoy.

[Khan academy pre-algebra playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQMU-lsMb3U&list=PL238F98B2C6422A95)